# Backbone.js - load initial route with backbone router and hashchange false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I run in a bit of trouble, in my application i want to default to page reload instead of hash urls when used in IE. This seems to be possible be using the hashChange option and setting it to false.

However that makes router not loading at all in IE, we would still like the backbone router to load the initial route associated with the loaded URL.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true,  hashChange: false});
```

Anyway of doing that?

Comment: For me it works exactly with the settings you stated above. Can you give an example of what's not working? Are you sure that your Backbone Root matches the URL given? If there's a mismatch then Backbone will not load at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pushState based on History support:

```
$(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({
  root: '/',
  pushState: (window.history && window.history.pushState),
  hashChange: false,
  silent: false
  });
});
```